# Uploading Public Keys from Microchip PIC IoT WG module for app migration

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to get a demo going for my client.

I have a Microchip IoT WG module which I have modified and ported the code to my target PIC microprocessor.  I started Google account and tried to register it without replacing authentication chip ATECC608A because programming it was near impossible.  I altered firmware to change the ID because you require the ID to start with a Alpha character.

I can extract the public key but cannot register the device without uploading public key.  It is in BASE64 format but not PEM encrypted.

I plan on buying trust and go parts from microchip.  I need information to straighten me out on what is required for PEM & registration of trust and go.

My app is equivalent to a home thermostat where control, monitoring, and troubleshooting of home systems would be desired by user (via Http: or phone app) and manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found some information about how to Get Started with Trust&GO and Google IoT Core in https://www.microchip.com/design-centers/security-ics/trust-platform/trust-go/trust-go-google-iot-core and some PEM information in the google docs https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/keys.